# Entering date in d/mm format in TextBox

Tags: .net, windows-8, .net-4.5, cultureinfo

I've got a TextBox bound to a nullable DateTime property.

I'm in Australia, so I want dates presented in the d/mm/yyyy format.

On my Windows 7 box, I can enter the date in d/mm format, and it's converted correctly (eg. 1/11 converts to November 1st, 13/1 converts to January 13th etc.)

On my Windows 8 box, the same input is interpreted as if it was in the US format, so 1/11 converts to January 11th, and 13/1 fails (since there is no 13th month).

Both computers are set to use the Australian formats, and I have this code in the Application.StartUp event:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(FrameworkElement), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)))
```

The Binding's StringFormat is set to d/MM/yyyy, and I've checked that this is correct by also binding a TextBlock to the same property that has its StringFormat set to D (the long date format, which gives values like 'Wednesday, 11 January, 2012').

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Update:** Further investigation (see comments below) reveals this seems to be an issue with the en-AU culture being different on Windows 8 compared to Windows 7, which means that it interprets dates like '1/11' in mm/dd format on Windows 8, whereas on Windows 7, it interprets them in dd/mm format, which is what I'd expect when using the en-AU culture.

Comment: Other things I've tried: setting `xml:lang="en-AU"` on the parent Window, setting `ConverterCulture=en-AU` on the Binding. Neither worked... (there isn't a converter on the Binding, but I figured I'd try it anyway)

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("1/11", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU")).Month` gives 11 on Windows 7, but 1 on Windows 8 - this isn't a WPF bug any more...

Comment: On Windows 8:
en-AU gives 1, en-GB gives 11, en-US gives 1, fr gives 11

Comment: How about a workaround where you use a ValueConverter instead. Is this a OneWay or TwoWay binding?

Comment: It's TwoWay. (I ended up just changing the LanguageProperty override to use en-GB for the time being, which isn't perfect, but it's pretty good.)

Comment: Given what you've found, you may want to adjust the question, and especially the tags. Sounds like us Aussies have a bad registry entry in Win8.

Comment: @MarkHurd I'm not sure whether it is a registry setting or not but we have recently had a similar issue on windows server 2012. The above line returns the month as `1`. So its not confined to Win8.

Comment: @JamesKhoury It hasn't affected me yet, but it looks like it should be listed on Connect as a problem then. (May be it is...)

Answer (score 1):

Since IetfLanguageTag is deprecated, have you considered using the Name property instead?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.ietflanguagetag.aspx:

> The format of an IETF language tag is similar to the culture name
>   returned by the Name property, but does not identify a culture
>   uniquely. That is, different cultures share the same IETF language tag
>   if those cultures have identical linguistic characteristics.

Comment: Using `Name` instead of `IetfLanguageTag` makes no difference, they're the same, both on Windows 7 and Windows 8. (As that page says - "IETF tags and names are identical.")

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthDayPattern = "dd MMMM";
```

Will update your current thread's Month and Day format. The `MonthDayPattern` changed in Windows Server 2012. I haven't figured out why yet.